# Another Name error for my text adventure game Python

Tags: python-3.x, adventure

So i am making a text adventure game, and currently i am making the enemies. My class random_enemies makes trash mobs for your character to fight and i have a function in it called weak, normal, strong, etc... that scales with your character depending on which one it is. When i call random_enemies.weak it says (Name Error: global variable "p" is not defined) even though it should be.

```
import random
from character import *
from player import *

class random_enemies(character):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,maxhp,attack_damage,ability_power,exp):
        super(random_enemies,self).__init__(name,hp,maxhp)
        self.attack_damage = attack_damage
        self.ability_power = ability_power
        self.exp = exp
    def weak():
        self.hp = random.randint(p.maxhp/10, p.maxhp/5)
        self.attack_damage = None
        self.ability_power = None
        self.exp = None



from character import*
class player(character):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,maxhp,attack_damage,ability_power):
        super(player,self).__init__(name, hp, maxhp)
        self.attack_damage = attack_damage
        self.ability_power = ability_power
```

This is my player class and below is the class that player gets "maxhp" from.

```
class character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,maxhp):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxhp = maxhp
    def attack(self,other):
        pass



p=player(Players_name, 100, 100, 10, 5,)
while (p.hp>0):
    a=input("What do you want to do?")
    if a=="Instructions":
        Instructions()
    elif a=="Commands":
        Commands()
    elif a=="Fight":
        print("Level",wave,"Wave Begins")
        if wave < 6:
            b = random_enemies.weak()
            print("A",b,"Appeared!")
            print("Stats of",b, ": \n Health=", b.hp,"Attack Damage=",b.attack_damage)
            continue
```

I just made this really quickly just to test if everything I had was working until I got the error. This is also the place where random_enemies.weak() was called. Also in this is where I defined what "p" was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all, follow a naming convention. For python code I recommend that you use [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as a convention.

You have a problem with classes vs. instances in your code. First, you need an instance of a class before you can use it:

```
enemy = random_enemy()  # a better name would be RandomEnemy
```

In Python, all methods start with `self`, and you need to pass to the method the arguments that it needs to do its work. `weak` is a method, so it should be more like this:

```
def weak(self, player):
   # the method for weak ... weak attack ?
   # remember to change p to player, which is more meaningful
   ...
```

Now that you have your instance and it has a method `weak` which receives a `player` as argument, you can use it as follows:

```
# you can't use random_enemy here as you tried because it is a class
# you need a random_enemy instance, the enemy that I talked about earlier
b = enemy.weak(player)  # renamed p to player because it is more meaningful
```

For this all to work, you will need one more thing. `weak()` needs to return something. Right now you are using what it returns, nothing! The code that you posted is `b = random_enemies.weak()`. Because `weak()` does not have a `return` clause, `b` will always be `None`.

Some notes: Avoid one-letter variables unless there is a long standing convention (like using `i` for loop counter). It is easier to understand what you are trying to do if you define `player` instead of just `p`.

Python has a really great [tutorial for all this stuff](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: This still throws an error because the `weak` method is also missing the `self` parameter (or be a static method). Furthermore, the call is just wrong in general as the `random_enemies` class is never instantiated - the way OP is using it suggests that `weak` should be static, in which case it should probably just be a factory method.

Comment: Yeah, I think I rushed in the answer assuming it was just one little thing, then I re-read the code in the question and realized there were lots of little things.

Comment: What I mean by "weak" is that it is a weak trash mob. Well currently i have a random name generator in the weak function that returns a random name for the weak monster. Didn't include it because i thought it was besides the point. This class is suppose to generate random monsters and the function makes it so your character is fighting a "weak" "strong" etc... monster. I still have the error (global variable p is not defined) :P